# bounded Cantor pairing?

Tags: functions, cantor-set, poker

I know this is not the coding stack exchange but the first three paragraphs just pertain to the background (I hope it is not too jargon heavy). My question itself is more mathematical. Also I don't have that much knowledge regarding mathematics.

I am a hobby programmer doing some things with poker abstraction. I currently have cards encoded as unique integers.

Anyway, For the purpose of constructing a unique id for each game-state (Hand, Flop etc...)  I would like to exploit a recursive pairing function which expands with the previous result and each new card that comes into play, and suite relations. I am aware of Cantor's pairing function and similar methods. But these will quickly overflow (i.e. the numbers become too large for my script to handle). But I am guessing it should be possible to construct a sort of 'bounded' pairing function in order to keep the expansion rate somewhat in check?

All be possible states in poker (barring bet-sequences) amount to 2,428,287,420. So it should be possible to create a function that maps each state to a max value of 2,428,287,420. For reference, the amount I can hold in a 3 byte integer (my goal) is 4,294,967,296.

I wish to instate a pairing function where one axis is 'bounded'. For example, in the image below:

[cantor pairing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3v3T.png)

if I knew A priori that for all usages of the function `y < 3` I would never have to map (0,3) to 9. Instead I could map (4,0) to 9 and thereby compress the output of my function. sadly I found little reference how to do this (or if it is possible with a relatively simple formula).

could you guys nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: With some pen and paper I came up with a solution: given that ymax is the boundary along the y axis and x > y I can use  ymax*x + x - y. Now I just have no idea how to do an unpair function?

Comment: What you are asking for is essentially a minimal perfect hash function. This is more of a [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) material than math.se. But anyway, this seems to me like an example of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What you (probably) need is a hash map (I doubt perfect hashing is strictly necessary for your applications).

Comment: By the way, hash maps (and probably perfect hashing as well, although you might have to dig more for that) are likely already implemented in the standard libraries for your language of choice (for example, in python, it is the built-in data structure of dictionary), there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I understand hash-maps is the go to way for this problem. But if the tables become sufficiently large they can also become somewhat slow. My idea is to create a unique id for each state, on the fly, which incorporates to current max value achieved. I can 1) use this id for clustering purposes and 2)  at the end of a non-bet sequence terminated game-cycle I can simply use the id and check it against the id of the opponents game-state to declare a winner. This would save a lot of hash lookups and I need to construct a unique game-state id anyway.